# ByteArray using Actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex

How to unload a ByteArray using ActionScript 3?
From memory

I tried:

```
// non-working solution no.1
byteArray.length = 0;
byteArray = new ByteArray();
//  non-working solution no.2
for ( var i:int=0; i < byteArray.length; i++ ) 
{
    byteArray[i] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution №1 per official documentation: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#clear()

```
byteArray.clear();
```